# how to select random question and print div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

what i want to do
I have 2 php pages
there are blank divs on the first page
there are questions I prepared on the second page
How can I print this div so that the questions are not the same every time the page is refreshed?
The for loop will loop according to the total dive on the page
I don't want to print 1 question to 2 dives

this is first page

```
for(var index=1; index<=2; index++){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "sorular.php",
                        success: function (data) {

                           $("#test1").html(data);
                           $("#test2").html(data);

                            }

                        });
                    }
```

this is second page

```
    echo <<<HTML

                <h3>Hangisi bir koşul ifadesidir?</h3>
                <input type="radio"  class="rd1" name="test" value="a"><span class="sp1">if sayi >0:</span>
                <input type="radio"  class="rd2" name="test" value="b"><span  class="sp2">if else sayi>!0:</span>
                <input type="radio"  class="rd3" name="test" value="c"><span  class="sp3">else else 1></span>
                <input type="button" value="Kontrol Et" class="first_btn" id="test1_btn">

HTML;
echo <<<HTML

                <h3>Hangisi bir koşul ifadesidir?</h3>
                <input type="radio"  class="rd1" name="test" value="a"><span class="sp1">if sayi >0:</span>
                <input type="radio"  class="rd2" name="test" value="b"><span  class="sp2">if else sayi>!0:</span>
                <input type="radio"  class="rd3" name="test" value="c"><span  class="sp3">else else 1></span>
                <input type="button" value="Kontrol Et" class="first_btn" id="test1_btn">

HTML;
```

Comment: As you are echoing out the questions from `sorural.php` you need to make sure that the echoing questions doesn't repeat there, the code you have provided doesn't give much knowledge to answer.